# Wierd results when trying to back trace inside an injected dll

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, stack-trace

Here is my problem. I detoured the "ScriptTextOut" function and I'm attempting to find where it was called from. Here is my dll (I use Microsoft Detour):

```
#pragma comment(lib, "detours.lib")

#include <Windows.h>
#include <detours.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Usp10.h>
#include <Dbghelp.h>

HRESULT (WINAPI * Real_ScriptTextOut)(const HDC hdc, SCRIPT_CACHE *psc, int x, int y, UINT fuOptions, const RECT *lprc, const SCRIPT_ANALYSIS *psa, const WCHAR *pwcReserved, int iReserved,
    const WORD *pwGlyphs, int cGlyphs, const int *piAdvance, const int *piJustify, const GOFFSET *pGoffset) = ScriptTextOut;

// function used to back trace where the function was called from
void printStack()
{
     unsigned int   i;
     void         * stack[ 100 ];
     unsigned short frames;
     SYMBOL_INFO  * symbol;
     HANDLE         process;

     process = GetCurrentProcess();

     SymInitialize( process, NULL, TRUE );

     frames               = CaptureStackBackTrace( 0, 100, stack, NULL );
     symbol               = ( SYMBOL_INFO * )calloc( sizeof( SYMBOL_INFO ) + 256 * sizeof( char ), 1 );
     symbol->MaxNameLen   = 255;
     symbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof( SYMBOL_INFO );

     for( i = 0; i < frames; i++ )
     {
         SymFromAddr( process, ( DWORD64 )( stack[ i ] ), 0, symbol );

         printf( "%i: %s - 0x%0X\n", frames - i - 1, symbol->Name, symbol->Address );
     }

     free( symbol );
}

// My ScriptTextOut function
HRESULT WINAPI Mine_ScriptTextOut(const HDC hdc, SCRIPT_CACHE *psc, int x, int y, UINT fuOptions, const RECT *lprc, const SCRIPT_ANALYSIS *psa, const WCHAR *pwcReserved, int iReserved,
    const WORD *pwGlyphs, int cGlyphs, const int *piAdvance, const int *piJustify, const GOFFSET *pGoffset)
{
    printStack();

    return Real_ScriptTextOut(hdc, psc, x, y, fuOptions, lprc, psa, pwcReserved, iReserved, pwGlyphs, cGlyphs, piAdvance, piJustify, pGoffset);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved  )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:

        AllocConsole();
        freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);

        DetourTransactionBegin(); 
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());

        DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)Real_ScriptTextOut, Mine_ScriptTextOut);

        DetourTransactionCommit();

        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        FreeConsole();

        DetourTransactionBegin(); 
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());

        DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)Real_ScriptTextOut, Mine_ScriptTextOut);

        DetourTransactionCommit();
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

So the detour function works as expected, but the printStack() function print some wierd results... Here, take a look:

[image: PrintStack output]

Why is it wierd, you may ask? Well, I expected to find the function that called ScriptTextOut, but the function before "Mine_ScriptTextOut" is "ScriptApplyDigitSubstitution", and while these 2 are clearly related, one doesn't call the other...

When testing my PrintStack function outside an injected dll, everything worked out fine:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Dbghelp.h>
#include <cstdio>

void printStack()
{
     unsigned int   i;
     void         * stack[ 100 ];
     unsigned short frames;
     SYMBOL_INFO  * symbol;
     HANDLE         process;

     process = GetCurrentProcess();

     SymInitialize( process, NULL, TRUE );

     frames               = CaptureStackBackTrace( 0, 100, stack, NULL );
     symbol               = ( SYMBOL_INFO * )calloc( sizeof( SYMBOL_INFO ) + 256 * sizeof( char ), 1 );
     symbol->MaxNameLen   = 255;
     symbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof( SYMBOL_INFO );

     for( i = 0; i < frames; i++ )
     {
         SymFromAddr( process, ( DWORD64 )( stack[ i ] ), 0, symbol );

         printf( "%i: %s - 0x%0X\n", frames - i - 1, symbol->Name, symbol->Address );
     }

     free( symbol );
}

void dontprint()
{
}

void foo()
{
    printStack();
}

void test()
{
    dontprint();
    foo();
}


int main()
{
    dontprint();
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the correct output:

[image: PrintStack correct output]

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: If you compile with frame pointer omission, you stack trace might not be 100 percent accurate.

Comment: I do not compile with frame pointer omission, so I don't think it's the problem...

Comment: More to the point, if the program (or libraries invoked thereby) you're injecting into is compiled with frame pointer omission, you'll have problems of the type you describe.

Comment: So there is really nothing I can do to get an accurate stack trace?

Comment: @Noob-programmer If you have the source of those libs you can recompile. Otherwise they have frame pointer omission, and that's that.